# Class return value doesn't pass the logical test

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class in Python which I'd like to return a value to the main game class so that I know if user exited the game (in which case I go back to the menu) or just wants the next level. For this purpose, I created such method in my game class:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.shouldIQuit
```

(self.shouldIQuit is True or False)

However, when I want to catch this value in the main class using this code:

```
        if self.startGame: #user started the game
            for i in range(4): #we iterate through all levels
                x = Game(i)
                print x
                if x == True: break #if user pressed Escape, he doesn't want to play anymore
```

And even though `print x` gives me correct outputs (True if I press Escape, False if I finish the level or press F5 to go to the next one), the logical test always fails and it just wants to load next level every single time... Why is that so? I tried casting the return value to string using `str()` but to no avail.

Comment: Why is this method `__repr__`? `__repr__` is supposed to return an unambiguous textual representation of an object, not whether or not the user wants to exit.

Comment: If you want to customize what happens when you compare using `==`, you need to override `__eq__`.  However, if you want to define boolean behavior, you should override `__bool__` as described in Veedrac's answer, and then do `if x` instead of `if x == True`.

Comment: @user2357112 - Umm, just because I thought that's the way to go if I want to return some value from a class in Python :( Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: @Straightfw: Yes - define a `should_quit` method for the class and call `x.should_quit()` to check.

Comment: @Straightfw: You can just use `x.shouldIQuit`, or write your own method if you want a method for it.

Comment: Oh my, surely... Sorry for a stupid question :)

Comment: A Method runs some code and (optionally) returns a value. A Class groups together methods that are logically related and/or depend on each other. Classes don't have "return values" as such.

Comment: @Basic - yes, yes, I know, just somehow came to the conclusion that in this particular case, it'd be the easiest for me to just have a return value from the class even though I have never heard of anything like it. To no surprise, I was wrong and it could be done the regular way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
x == True
```

checks if `x` is logically equal to `True`, not if it prints to `True`. You *could* encode the logic as

```
if str(x) == str(True)
```

but it'd be much better to define `__nonzero__(self)` (`__bool__` in Python 3) to return `self.shouldIQuit`. Then you can do

```
if x
```

And you can override `__eq__(self, other)` to check for equality with the `shouldIQuit` attribute if you must.

---

But really, that's silly too. The logical truthiness shouldn't have much to do with whether it's quitting or not.

Comment: Seems like a situation that would call for raising a custom `QuitException` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, as I said - I tried casting it to string and it didn't change much. Now that I tried overriding __bool__ instead of __repr__, the same thing happens - `print x` outputs `True` but `print x == True` outputs False...

Comment: `__bool__` only defines whether it is truthy, not whether it is equal to true.

Comment: Note that `__bool__` is spelled `__nonzero__` in Python 2.

Comment: Thanks. Edited to reflect OP's usage.